# Query on Storyboard segues

Tags: ios, storyboard

I have 3 view controllers A, B, C and the following custom segues are available:

A -> B

A -> C

B -> C

B <- C

A <- B

A <- C

Now, the execution sequence is as follows:

Click a button in A and A -> B happens.

Click a button in B and B -> C happens.

Now, I will need the following to happen:

Click a button in C and A should appear directly. If I perform C -> A segue, it shows me the B screen as B is added on A. If I perform, C -> B and B -> A in order, it works for me but I dont want B to appear here. How to get this one solved?

Thanks.

Comment: What is being executed when you press the button on C?

Comment: I am doing C -> A now, but B is being shown.

Comment: I get that, but show us the code.

Comment: I just do a perform segue in this case:        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueCToA" sender:self]; And I will set some states in A.

Comment: What *kind* of segues are these?

Comment: You shouldn't go backwards from C or B unless you use an unwind segue. If you do that, you're actually creating new instances of the controllers you're "going back" to. Since the controllers have a strong pointer to each other (if you're doing modal segues), none of the controllers ever gets deallocated, and you'll just keep piling up more and more controllers as you move back and forth.

Comment: @rdelmar I have implemented a custom unwind segue to go back to previous view controllers either A or B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a custom segue for B->C. It removes 'B' from A and sets the parent of C to A as follows in the perform function in my custom segue class.

```
- (void)perform
{
     UIViewController *B = self.sourceViewController;
     UIViewController *C = self.destinationViewController;
     UIViewController *A = source.parentViewController;

     [A addChildViewController:B];
     [B willMoveToParentViewController:nil];

     [A transitionFromViewController:source
                   toViewController:destination
                           duration:1.0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionNone
                         animations:^{
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             [B removeFromParentViewController];
                             [C didMoveToParentViewController:container];
  }];
}
```

Then if I call my remove segue C->A, it removes C and shows A without B.

Comment: You shouldn't need a custom segue to do this. A standard unwind segue from C to A should do what you want.